# How to use client.read() to read string between two characters?

Tags: wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

In my ESP8266 WiFi project I'm getting characters from a website through a GET request. The current code is this:

```cpp
while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
}
```

To get a string between particular characters, how do I edit this?

Comment: Does the below answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the code snip after read string operation and change the below divider delimeters with yours and **gatheredStr**   will be your desired string:

```
char firstDivider = 'X';
char secondDivider = 'Y';
int firstDividerIndex = line.indexOf(firstDivider);
int secondDividerIndex = line.indexOf(secondDivider);
String gatheredStr = line.substring(firstDividerIndex, secondDividerIndex);
```

Comment: thanks for this code snip. But what if i have a string like this 'ssid=appollo&auth=wap2&pass=12345' i need all the strings between all the '=' and the '&'.

Comment: I can suggest you sscanf function.
sscanf("ssid=%s&auth=%s&pass=%s",ssid,auth,pass);